# Better way of getting time in milliseconds in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Is there an alternative in JavaScript of getting time in milliseconds using the date object, or at least a way to reuse that object, without having to instantiate a new object every time I need to get this value? I am asking this because I am trying to make a simple game engine in JavaScript, and when calculating the "delta frame time", I have to create a new Date object every frame. While I am not too worried about the performance implications of this, I am having some problems with the reliability of the exact time returned by this object.

I get some strange "jumping" in the animation, every second or so, and I am not sure if this is related to JavaScript's Garbage Collection or a limitation of the Date object when updating so fast. If I set the delta value to some constant, then the animation if perfectly smooth, so I am fairly sure this "jumping" is related to the way I get the time.

The only relevant code I can give is the way I calculate the delta time :

```
prevTime = curTime;
curTime = (new Date()).getTime();
deltaTime = curTime - prevTime;
```

When calculating movement / animation I multiply a constant value with the delta time.

If there is no way to avoid getting the time in milliseconds by using the Date object, would a function that increments a variable (being the elapsed time in milliseconds since the game started), and which is called using the SetTimer function at a rate of once every milliseconds be an efficient and reliable alternative?

Edit : I have tested now my code in different browsers and it seems that this "jump" is really only apparent in Chrome, not in Firefox. But it would still be nice if there were a method that worked in both browsers.

Comment: One object per frame is *nothing*

Comment: About the animation jumping every second, could this have anything to do with the fact that `Date.getMilliseconds` returns only the milliseconds in the current second, i.e. 0 to 999? You aren't using this function in your example, but maybe it's being used somewhere else, or on a different branch?

Comment: Is the jumping related to some weird millisecond resolution issues? From the [Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now): "When using now() to create timestamps or unique IDs, keep in mind that the resolution may be 15 milliseconds on Windows".  Could that be related to the hiccups?

Comment: @zashu this was a long time ago, so I don't remember any specifics for this example. But for more recent application, when using Date.now() I see no more jumping.

Answer (score 199, accepted):

Try [Date.now()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now).

The skipping is most likely due to garbage collection. Typically garbage collection can be avoided by reusing variables as much as possible, but I can't say specifically what methods you can use to reduce garbage collection pauses.

Comment: I have tried using Date.now(), but I still have the same jumps. So now I am pretty certain that it isn't a problem with garbage collection, but rather a limitation when getting exact values with the Date object. Like I said, replacing delta time with a constant value results in smooth animations / transitions, so the only garbage collection that might be happening is with "new Date" or "Date.now()" (if this function instantiates it's own objects that I don't know about).

Comment: Just a heads up: This does not work in IE8 and below

Comment: I do:/
All I want is the date in ms. Seems so complicated for something so necessary.

Comment: @Prozi +1 .. IE really sucks, when Im web programming I really dont care about IE , just chrome and firefox ..........

Comment: @TechLife You should also give Android, Safari, and opera browsers a line of thought, but I agree IE is a load of rubbish. I mean it's so bad that MS have given up and are implementing a new browser in W10

Answer (score 60):

As far that I know you only can get time with *Date*.

*Date.now* is the solution but is not available everywhere : https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now.

```
var currentTime = +new Date();
```

This gives you the current time in milliseconds.

For your *jumps*. If you compute **interpolations** correctly according to the **delta frame time** and you don't have some **rounding number error**, I bet for the garbage collector (GC).

If there is a lot of created temporary object in your loop, garbage collection has to lock the thread to make some cleanup and memory re-organization.

With Chrome you can see how much time the GC is spending in the *Timeline* panel.

EDIT: Since my answer, `Date.now()` should be considered as the best option as it is supported everywhere and on IE >= 9.

Comment: What function does the `+` serve in `+new`?

Comment: The `+` simply cast `Date` to `Number`, giving a standard unix timestamp in milliseconds. You can explicitly get this value by calling `(new Date()).getTime()`

Comment: @mikenelson: Not terrible for me, this is obvious when you know how coercion works.That said, `Date.now()` is prefered now as its support is large enough now.

Comment: I prefer just `+` than `.getTime()` ... It's simpler and I don't need memorize function names

Comment: @TravisJ Awesome shortcut? To retrieve a numeric value that is already inside your computer you create an object, call an operator that tests for an int and triggers a conversion that calls a function (valueOf) that calls the class conversion method that calls a function (getTime) that finally retrieves the value. Then the object is abandoned to its destiny, and after 1000 iterations of the loop you have 1000 deleted Date objects requiring garbage collection hanging there that suddenly get all dumped together, and while your computer lags you wonder what is happening. :)  Awesome!

Comment: @FrancescoMM Always look at the initial date (2012), and the edit also. At that time you didn't have any other choice if you wanted to support all browsers. You had to allocate a `Date` object.

Comment: @ngryman that doesn't make it, expecially the conversion to int, an awesome shortcut. A simple new Date().getTime() was still better in 2012. Mine was a reply to TravisJ.

Comment: You were complaining about allocations. Your version still allocates an object... So on that point there is no difference. The only remaining is implicit coercion versus method call, which has no real world impact on performance, except if you call it 10e9 times per frames which is not a realistic use case. And I'm not even sure coercion was slower as it implicitly calls valueOf which just returns the internal timestamp, like getTime does. "Better" is really more a matter of taste here than a realistic performance problem...

Answer (score 54):

I know this is a pretty old thread, but to keep things up to date and more relevant, you can use the more accurate [`performance.now()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/performance) functionality to get finer grain timing in javascript.

```
window.performance = window.performance || {};
performance.now = (function() {
    return performance.now       ||
        performance.mozNow    ||
        performance.msNow     ||
        performance.oNow      ||
        performance.webkitNow ||            
        Date.now  /*none found - fallback to browser default */
})();
```

Comment: The last alternative should be just `Date.now` instead of a anonymous function expression

Comment: Also doesn't work in stupid old browsers, unfortunately. Luckily, I've convinced my clients to pay me for the time I waste supporting IE7 and IE8.

Comment: || function() { return new Date().getTime() }

Comment: Worth noting that `performance.now()` gives monotonic time, unlike the time from `Date`. It means that every subsequent call is guaranteed to return a value not less than the previous one.

Comment: Do not forget: `performance.now()` gives a time based on window tab session. So, every time you refresh the page, the value will be `0000.00` again. Use `(new Date()).getTime` when you want to storage the timming to check later, in case the user refresh the session.

Comment: The output of ``performance.now()`` is not comparable to that of ``Date.now()``. It is meant for timing purposes, meaning that if you want it to represent a timestamp you need to use ``performance.timeOrigin + performance.now()``

Answer (score 15):

If you have date object like

```
var date = new Date('2017/12/03');
```

then there is inbuilt method in javascript for getting date in milliseconds format which is **valueOf()**

```
date.valueOf(); //1512239400000 in milliseconds format
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a very old question - but still for reference if others are looking at it - [`requestAnimationFrame()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.requestAnimationFrame) is the right way to handle animation in modern browsers:

UPDATE:  The mozilla link shows how to do this - I didn't feel like repeating the text behind the link ;)

Comment: Welcome to [so]! You might want to include a short explanation of what `requestAnimationFrame` does that stops this "jumping" as described in the question. Thanks!

Comment: Even with requestAnimationFrame we're not meant to assume the frame rate is the same on all platforms, so we still need to check the current time.