# jquery progress bar to count seconds and stop on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have checked quite a few of the progress bars on the internet but none seem to handle the following case:

1. show a progress bar which updates automatically in the background as a function of time. e.g. to be simple the jqueryUI progress bar which would update automatically in the background every second until 5 seconds (at 5s it is at 100% and stops).
2. Possibility of clicking somewhere to stop it.

The use case for this is in simple games for children where progress is shown but when the task is completed there is a simple way to stop the progress bar.

Is there an easy way to implement this in jquery/javascript?

**Edit**, from DavidKonrad's accepted answer, I have created a small typescript class, with the additional support for _gProgressAlive to query if progress is running, and a callback to take action when progress is done.  Here is the result,  hope it helps others!

```
var  _gProgressStatus=0;
var _gProgressMax=3;
var _gProgressIncrement=1000;
var _gProgress;
var _gProgressAlive=false;
class ProgressBar{

static stop() {
  clearInterval(_gProgress);
  _gProgressAlive=false;

}

static start(endCallback){
    _gProgressAlive=true;
     _gProgressStatus=0;
  _gProgress = setInterval(function() {
  _gProgressStatus++; 
  $("#progressbar").progressbar({
   value :_gProgressStatus,max:_gProgressMax
  });
  if (_gProgressStatus >=  _gProgressMax){ ProgressBar.stop();endCallback();}
}, _gProgressIncrement);
}

}
```

and here is the main html test markup

```
<script>
ProgressBar.start(function(){   
    console.log("completed, time's up");
    console.log(_gProgressAlive); // false progress is complete, this is the callback
});
    console.log(_gProgressAlive); // should output true, progress bar has started
  </script>
<div id="progressbar"></div>
```

Comment: Write it in JS/jQuery. Use Date.now() [ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4874408/better-way-of-getting-time-in-milliseconds-in-javascript ] to store start time. Calculate percent and update it every 0.1 sec with some function you run at page load by setInterval [ http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp ]
 This progress bar looks like it support any type of bar you want: http://jqueryui.com/progressbar/#indeterminate - - - - - - if you need help in JS then answer this comment and I will post you example code to controll progress bar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, yes - it is easy to implement. It would have been even more easier if you have provided an example of markup and what you have tried until now as well :)

markup :

```html
<div id="progressbar"></div>
```

script :

```js
$("#progressbar").progressbar({
  value: 0,
  max : 5  
});

var value = 0,
    progress;

function stopProgress() {
  clearInterval(progress);
  $("#progressbar").progressbar({
     value : 0
  });
}

progress = setInterval(function() {
  value++; 
  $("#progressbar").progressbar({
    value : value
  });
  if (value == 5) clearInterval(progress);
}, 1000);

$(window).on('click', function() {
   stopProgress();
});
```

jQueryUI demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/vqadbkj9/**

Answer (score -1):

Stopping a progress bar implies that the task is completed. So, it should show filled status on being stopped. I am assuming that is what you meant. Here's the code:

HTML:

```
<body onload="expand()">
    <div id="parent">
        <div id="child"></div>
    </div>
    <button onclick="stop()">Stop</button>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
#parent
{
    width:100px;
    height:10px;
    background-color:rgb(100,100,100);
}

#child
{
    float:left;
    width:0px;
    height:10px;
    background-color:red;
    transition: all 5s linear;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
function expand()
{
    document.getElementById("child").style.width = "100px";
}

function stop()
{
    document.getElementById("parent").style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
```

Comment: This is very far from the main point which is to create the progressbar and have it update automatically as a function of time.